# document.createElement('p').setAttribute('onclick', 'view()') not working

Tags: javascript

I am having a slight problem with the .setAttribute command. I am creating an element called view:

```
var view = document.createElement('p')
view.innerHTML = "VIEW"
view.style.color = "#e60f0f"
view.style.fontFamily = "Montserrat"
view.style.fontWeight = "600"
view.style.fontSize = "13px"
view.style.right = "5px"
view.style.position = "absolute"
view.style.top = "0px"
view.style.marginTop = "5px"
view.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"
view.style.padding = "10px"
view.style.borderRadius = "7px"
view.setAttribute('onclick', 'view(name, date, type)')
document.getElementById(newId).appendChild(view)
```

When I run this, everything renders except the .setAttribute() function. I don't have the sligthest idea why. Does anyone know? Thank you SO much!

Here's the view() function in case you need it:

```
function view(name, date, type) {
  window.location = '/flightStatus?name=' + name + '&date=' + date + '&type=' + type
}
```

*Just as another note: I am sending this to Node.js... I don't think that matters, the code above is client-side :)*

Comment: Where are the `name`, `date`, and `type` variables defined? Are they arguments or something, or defined inside a function?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045). Don't use inline handlers, they have a demented scope chain, require global pollution, and have quote escaping issues. Use `addEventListener` instead

Comment: Those variable are defined above.

Comment: Ok, but are they arguments, or inside a function, or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the variables in this line:
`view.setAttribute('onclick', 'view(name, date, type)')`

I would've used template literals:

```
view.setAttribute('onclick', `view(${name}, ${date}, ${type})`)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

If you are unsure of whether to use addEventListener or onClick:

[addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You would only be able to use strings in your inline method. That would looks something like this (or using template literals):

```js
view.setAttribute('onclick', 'view(\'' + name + '\', \'' + date + '\', \'' + type + '\')')
```

You should use proper DOM Methods though. Simply replace

```js
view.setAttribute('onclick', 'view(name, date, type)')
```

with

```js
view.addEventListener('click', () => view(name, date, type));
```